# Drag and drop functionality in ADF Calendars

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a doctors schedule set in my ADF Calendar, say he has an appointment on 11.00 am but at the same time he has a personal emergency. He wants to reschedule the appointment to 11am the next day. This can be done using a form where in he performs an update or another way could be drag the appointment from the current date and drop it to the next date in the calendar view which seems a really attractive solution.

I am not sure if this is possible in ADF calendar, has anyone tried this or even if someone has another solution please do advice. I am open to suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Calendar's drag and drop functionality to achieve this. Here are the steps:

- Add 'Calendar Drop Target' as a child to Calendar:
- Add the code required for setting dragged activity start and end date in respect to drop target date in calendarDropListener,as guided in [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/b31973/af_dnd.htm#ADFUI10125)

For detailed implementation of calendarDropListener have a look at [Implementing Drag and Drop functionality in ADF Calendar](http://adftidbits.blogspot.com/2014/12/implementing-drag-and-drop.html)

Comment: I tried that but am facing issues like what is the type of data flavor I am supposed to use. Is there some kind of sample specific to calendar.

Comment: If you want to drag the activities from within the calendar,  org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.model.RowKeySet will work as data flavor. But, if you want to drag some activity from outside the calendar, like string or date type component then you need to specify those types as data flavors. Here is a calendar drag-drop demo http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/calendarDropTarget.jspx;jsessionid=0bdad7f817ec4039062d3ba86e06